# Android EditText - Type over existing text?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

Let's say we have few `EditText` defined as following:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:digits="123456789"
            android:ems="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
```

These `EditText` can have only 1 digit 1-9. Few of them have set an digit as their text.

When the user is trying to write a new digit in an `EditText` that represents a digit already, he have to delete the old digit and type the new one.

My question is how can you make an `EditText` type over the digit without having to delete the old digit. 
I do not want to delete the digit when the user clicks the `EditText`,
but only when he tries to type a new digit.

I would be very happy if there is an XML property for this, but if not I will be happy to see a Java code to solve this.

Comment: You have the max length set to 1.  That means it can only have 1 character in it.  Remove that if you want multiple digits in there.  If you mean you want him to overwrite as soon as he taps a key, select the text when the user taps on the view.  Selections are overwritten as you type.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I need it to be only one character. I want to override the character as soon as the user types in. Is there a way without selection?

Comment: No.  That's the way you do overwriting in most OSes.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok thank you, I will use selection and manipulate the selection highlight color. This is actually a good and easy solution.

Comment: Or onFocus set a boolean flag and onKeyPress if that flag is true setText("")